# How could I use Jython threads as they were Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, jython

For example I want to reproduce this Thread in Jython because I need  to start my **statemachine** from a Java API.I dont own much knowledge in Jython. How can I do that?

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        statemachine.enter();
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            statemachine.getInterfaceNew64().getVarMessage();
            statemachine.runCycle();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                interrupt();
            }
       }            
    }
};
thread.start();
```

So I'm trying something like this:

```
class Cycle(Thread, widgets.Listener):
    def run(self):
        self.statemachine = New64CycleBasedStatemachine()
        self.statemachine.enter()
        while not self.currentThread().isInterrupted():
            self.statemachine.getInterfaceNew64().getVarMessage()
            self.statemachine.runCycle()
            try: 
                self.currentThread().sleep(100)
            except InterruptedException: 
                self.interrupt()
        self.start()

foo = Cycle()
foo.run()
#foo.start()
```

PS: I already tried to do what is commented under the foo.run()

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, putting aside the fact that you are calling the `start()` method from within the `run()` method, which is a really bad idea because once a thread is started, if you attempt to start it again you will get a thread state exception, setting that aside, the problem is, most probably, that you are using Jython threading library and not Java's.

If you make sure to import as follows:

```
from java.lang import Thread, InterruptedException
```

Instead of

```
from threading import Thread, InterruptedException
```

And if you correct the problem I cited above, chances are that your code will run just fine.

Using the Jython's `threading` library, you would need to change the code a bit, somewhat like:

```
from threading import Thread, InterruptedException
import time

class Cycle(Thread):
    canceled = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.canceled:
            try:
                print "Hello World"
                time.sleep(1)
            except InterruptedException:
                canceled = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Cycle()
    foo.start()
```

Which appears to work for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think my problem it wasnt with the thread and just with my statemachine. Thank you very much for your attention!